# Optimization of batch matrix multiplications

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I've got roughly the following:

```
A = rand(10, 20, 30);
B = rand(10, 30, 40);
```

I'd like to get a matrix `C` of size `(10, 20, 40)`, and currently doing it using a for loop:

```
for i = 1:10
    C(i, :, :) = squeeze(A(i, :, :)) * squeeze(B(i, :, :));
end
```

I tried doing `C = bsxfun(@mtimes, A, B);`, but that doesn't work.

What's the best way to optimize this? I'm not looking for pretty-readable code, only for the most optimize thing I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: your current method looks the right way. Is it slow? It takes `0.0003s` in my PC. Note that you need to squeeze each matrix, not the result of the multiplication.

Comment: It's not fast at all on my machine, I'm assuming the `for` loop is to blame. Note that the `A` and `B` are much bigger in my app.

Comment: Did you preallocate `C` properly?

Comment: yes, using `zeros`.

Comment: @galah92 certainly the speed will depend on the size, this is clear. The time I showed is the time for the entire loop example you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I start, it's important to realize that matrix multiplication is a very expensive process. It's asymptotic complexity is O(n^3) (O(n^2.8) with strassens). This means that while you might not think you are doing a lot of calculations, there are really billions of calculations happening that you don't even know about. Because of this, there is a limit to how much you can really do due to the sheer number of calculations.

There are 2 ways of doing batch matrix multiplication in MATLAB if you do not wish to use for loops.

The first is a function called [mtimesx](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support). This function once compiled uses sparse matrices to vectorize the process. However, the matrices have to be in the first 2 dimensions. In code this operation would be.

```
A = rand(10, 20, 30);
B = rand(10, 30, 40);
A = permute(A,[2 3 1]); % Change the dimensions as mtimesx always multiplies the first 2 dimensions
B = permute(B,[2 3 1]);
C = mtimesx(A,B);
C = permute(C,[3 1 2]);
```

This would do the operation described by your problem usually much faster.

Alternatively, if you have a GPU, you can use [pagefun](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/pagefun.html) in the same way.

```
A = rand(10, 20, 30);
B = rand(10, 30, 40);
A = permute(A,[2 3 1]);
B = permute(B,[2 3 1]);
A = gpuArray(A);
B = gpuArray(B);
C = pagefun(@mtimes,A,B);
C = permute(C,[3 1 2]);
```

This method sends out each problem onto a page of the GPU, if you use single precision, this method is usually much faster than mtimesx.

I adapted @MarcinKonowalczyk script to run all of the examples. As you can see, mtimesx, in this case, performs the best with a considerable improvement over the other methods

[image: Results of all methods]

Additionally, this plot uses 1000 matrix multiplications instead of 10, here we begin to see the advantage of GPU over CPU.

[image: Results with 1000 matrix multiplies]

```
close all; clear;

N = 1000;
N = N+10; % Add a few initial runs to be trimmed off at the end

%% 1st dimension
% Preallocate C
num_problems = 10;
outer_left = 20;
inner = 30;
outer_right = 40;
A = rand(num_problems, outer_left, inner); B = rand(num_problems, inner, outer_right); C = zeros(num_problems, outer_left, outer_right);

t1 = zeros(1,N); % Preallocate timing results vector
for j = 1:N % Do the multiplication N times
    tic
    for i = 1:num_problems
        C(i, :, :) = squeeze(A(i, :, :)) * squeeze(B(i, :, :));
    end
    t1(j) = toc;
end

%% 2nd dimension
A = permute(A,[2 1 3]); B = permute(B,[2 1 3]); C = permute(C,[2 1 3]);

t2 = zeros(1,N);
for j = 1:N
    tic
    for i = 1:num_problems
        C(:, i, :) = squeeze(A(:, i, :)) * squeeze(B(:, i, :));
    end
    t2(j) = toc;
end

%% 3rd dimension
A = permute(A,[1 3 2]); B = permute(B,[1 3 2]); C = permute(C,[1 3 2]);

t3 = zeros(1,N);
for j = 1:N
    tic
    for i = 1:num_problems
        C(:, :, i) = A(:, :, i) * B(:, :, i);
    end
    t3(j) = toc;
end

t4 = zeros(1,N);
for ii = 1:N
    tic
    C = mtimesx(A,B);
    t4(ii) = toc;
end

A = gpuArray(A);
B = gpuArray(B);
t5 = zeros(1,N);
for ii = 1:N
    tic
    C = pagefun(@mtimes,A,B);
    t5(ii) = toc;
end

%% Plot

% Trim initial runs and convert to microsecconds
t1 = t1(11:end)*1e6; t2 = t2(11:end)*1e6; t3 = t3(11:end)*1e6;
t4 = t4(11:end)*1e6; t5 = t5(11:end)*1e6;

x = 1:N-10;
plot(x,t1,x,t2,x,t3,x,t4,x,t5);

grid on;
xlabel('trial number');
ylabel('running time / us');
legend('C(i,:,:)','C(:,i,:)','C(:,:,i)','mtimesx','pagefun');
title(sprintf('t1 = %.0f, t2 = %.0f, t3 = %.0f, t4 = %.0f, t5 = %.0f us',median(t1),median(t2),median(t3),median(t4),median(t5)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the dimension over which you itterate to optimise memory access. After all, your matrices are [stored in memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) as long 1D arrays. Slicing them differently can may (and does) acess the neighbouring values as opposed to jumping all around the place. Your code would be:

```
A = rand(20, 30, 10);
B = rand(30, 40, 10);
C = zeros(20, 40, 10);

for i = 1:10
    C(:, :, i) = A(:, :, i) * B(:, :, i);
end
```

Note you don't even need the `squeeze` as Matlab automatically drops the trailing singleton dimension so you shave a few constant us off due to less function calls.

[image]
Here is the code I used:

```
close all; clear; clc;

N = 1000;
N = N+10; % Add a few initial runs to be trimmed off at the end

%% 1st dimension
% Preallocate C
A = rand(10, 20, 30); B = rand(10, 30, 40); C = zeros(10, 20, 40);

t1 = zeros(1,N); % Preallocate timing results vector
for j = 1:N % Do the multiplication N times
    tic
    for i = 1:10
        C(i, :, :) = squeeze(A(i, :, :)) * squeeze(B(i, :, :));
    end
    t1(j) = toc;
end

%% 2nd dimension
A = rand(20, 10, 30); B = rand(30, 10, 40); C = zeros(20, 10, 40);

t2 = zeros(1,N);
for j = 1:N
    tic
    for i = 1:10
        C(:, i, :) = squeeze(A(:, i, :)) * squeeze(B(:, i, :));
    end
    t2(j) = toc;
end

%% 3rd dimension
A = rand(20, 30, 10); B = rand(30, 40, 10); C = zeros(20, 40, 10);

t3 = zeros(1,N);
for j = 1:N
    tic
    for i = 1:10
        C(:, :, i) = A(:, :, i) * B(:, :, i);
    end
    t3(j) = toc;
end

%% Plot

% Trim initial runs and convert to microsecconds
t1 = t1(11:end)*1e6; t2 = t2(11:end)*1e6; t3 = t3(11:end)*1e6;

x = 1:N-10;
plot(x,t1,x,t2,x,t3);

grid on;
xlabel('trial number');
ylabel('running time / us');
legend('C(i,:,:)','C(:,i,:)','C(:,:,i)');
title(sprintf('t1 = %.0f, t2 = %.0f, t3 = %.0f us',median(t1),median(t2),median(t3)));
```